# Collection<T> versus List<T> what should you use on your interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, code-analysis

The code looks like below:

```
namespace Test
{
    public interface IMyClass
    {
        List<IMyClass> GetList();
    }

    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        public List<IMyClass> GetList()
        {
            return new List<IMyClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I Run Code Analysis i get the following recommendation.

> Warning    3   CA1002 : Microsoft.Design : Change 'List' in 'IMyClass.GetList()' to use Collection, ReadOnlyCollection or KeyedCollection

How should I fix this and what is good practice here?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

To answer the "why" part of the question as to why not [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), The reasons are future-proofing and API simplicity.

**Future-proofing**

[`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) is not designed to be easily extensible by subclassing it; it is designed to be fast for internal implementations. You'll notice the methods on it are not virtual and so cannot be overridden, and there are no hooks into its [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add)/[`Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert)/[`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove) operations.

This means that if you need to alter the behavior of the collection in the future (e.g. to reject null objects that people try to add, or to perform additional work when this happens such as updating your class state) then you need to change the type of collection you return to one you can subclass, which will be a breaking interface change (of course changing the semantics of things like not allowing null may also be an interface change, but things like updating your internal class state would not be).

So by returning either a class that can be easily subclassed such as [`Collection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1) or an interface such as [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1), [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) or [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) you can change your internal implementation to be a different collection type to meet your needs, without breaking the code of consumers because it can still be returned as the type they are expecting.

**API Simplicity**

[`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) contains a lot of useful operations such as [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch), [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort) and so on. However if this is a collection you are exposing then it is likely that you control the semantics of the list, and not the consumers. So while your class internally may need these operations it is very unlikely that consumers of your class would want to (or even should) call them.

As such, by offering a simpler collection class or interface, you reduce the number of members that users of your API see, and make it easier for them to use.

Comment: This response is dead on.  Another good read on the subject can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20090608080454/http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx

Comment: I see your first points, but I don't know if I agree on your API simplicity part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/398988/2632991 Here is a real good post too, about what is the difference between Collections and Lists.

Comment: Working link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2005/09/26/why-we-dont-recommend-using-listt-in-public-apis/

Comment: I see below that Skeet himself advocates interfaces (at time of writing at least). But ive seen a LOT of hardcore proponents that return types should be as concrete and specific as possible. Is your stance also that interfaces are only for when you really see a concrete situation where you might return different list types for example. Or do you feel there is reason to default to interface usage?

Answer (score 62):

I would personally declare it to return an interface rather than a concrete collection. If you really want list access, use [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx). Otherwise, consider [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

Comment: Would the IList then extend the ICollection interface?

Comment: Yes, IList<T> extends ICollection<T>. I'll add documentation links.

Comment: @Jon: I know this is old, but can you comment on what Krzysztof says at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx?  Specifically his comment, `We recommend using Collection<T>, ReadOnlyCollection<T>, or KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem> for outputs and properties and interfaces IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>, IList<T> for inputs.`  CA1002 seems to go along with Krzysztof's comments.  I can't imagine why a concrete collection would be recommended instead of an interface, and why the distinction between inputs/outputs.

Comment: @Nelson: It's rare that you want to *require* callers to pass in an immutable list, but it's reasonable to *return* one so that they know it's definitely immutable. Not sure about the other collections though. Would be nice to have more detail.

Comment: It's not for a specific case.  Obviously in general `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wouldn't make sense for an input.  Similarly, `IList<T>` as an input says, "I need Sort() or some other member that an IList has" which doesn't make sense for an output.  But what I meant was, why would `ICollection<T>` be recommended as an input and `Collection<T>` as an output.  Why *not* use `ICollection<T>` as the output also as you suggested?

Comment: @Nelson: I don't know, to be honest. It would be good to get more information from Krzysztof.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with inambiguity.  `Collection<T>` and `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` both derive from `ICollection<T>` (i.e. there is no `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`).  If you return the interface, it's not obvious which one it is and whether it can be modified.  Anyway, thanks for your input.  This was a good sanity check for me.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think anyone has answered the "why" part yet... so here goes. The reason "why" you "should" use a `Collection<T>` instead of a `List<T>` is because if you expose a `List<T>`, then anyone who gets access to your object can modify the items in the list. Whereas `Collection<T>` is supposed to indicate that you are making your own "Add", "Remove", etc. methods.

You likely don't need to worry about it, because you're probably coding the interface for yourself only (or maybe a few colleagues). Here's another example that might make sense.

If you have a public array, ex:

```
public int[] MyIntegers { get; }
```

You would think that because there is only a "get" accessor that no-one can mess with the values, but that's not true. Anyone can change the values inside there just like this:

```
someObject.MyIntegers[3] = 12345;
```

Personally, I would just use `List<T>` in most cases. But if you are designing a class library that you are going to give out to random developers, and you need to rely on the state of the objects... then you'll want to make your own Collection and lock it down from there :)

Comment: "If you return List<T> to the client code, you will not ever be able to receive notifications when client code modifies the collection." - FX COP... See also "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx"... wow, seems I'm not off base after all :)

Comment: Wow - years later I see that the link I pasted in the above comment had a quote at the end of it, so it didn't work... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly about abstracting your own implementations away instead of exposing the List object to be manipulated directly.

It's not good practice to let other objects (or people) modify the state of your objects directly. Think property getters/setters.

Collection -> For normal collection
ReadOnlyCollection -> For collections that shouldn't be modified
KeyedCollection -> When you want dictionaries instead.

How to fix it depends on what you want your class to do and the purpose of the GetList() method. Can you elaborate?

Comment: But Collection<T> and KeyedCollection<,> are not readonly either.

Comment: @nawfal And where did I say that it is?

Comment: You state *not let other objects (or people) modify the state of your objects directly* and list 3 collection types. Barring `ReadOnlyCollection` the other two doesn't obey it.

Comment: That's referring to "good practice". Proper context please. That list below simply state the basic requirement of such types since the OP wants to understand the warning. I then go on to ask him about the purpose of `GetList()` as to be able to help him more correctly.

Comment: In no way did I state that using the 3 types will immediately gets you to a "good practice" position.

Comment: Ok fine I understand that part. But still the reasoning part is not sound according to me. You say `Collection<T>` helps in abstracting internal implementation and prevents direct manipulation of internal list. How? `Collection<T>` is merely a wrapper, operating on the same instance passed. It's a dynamic collection meant for inheritance, nothing else (Greg's answer is more relevant here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57020/discussion-between-nawfal-and-chakrit).

Answer (score 1):

In these kind of case I usually try to expose the least amount of implemententation that is needed. If the consumers do not need to know that you are actually using a list then you don't need to return a list. By returning as Microsoft suggests a Collection you hide the fact that you are using a list from the consumers of your class and isolate them against an internal change.

Answer (score 1):

Something to add though it's been a long time since this was asked.

When your list type derives from `List<T>` instead of `Collection<T>`, you cannot implement the protected virtual methods that `Collection<T>` implements.
What this means is that you derived type cannot respond in case any modifications are made to the list. This is because `List<T>` assumes you are aware when you add or remove items. Being able to response to notifications is an overhead and hence `List<T>` doesn't offer it.

In cases when external code has access to your collection, you may not be in control of when an item is being added or removed. Therefore `Collection<T>` provides a way to know when your list was modified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with returning something like

```
this.InternalData.Filter(crteria).ToList();
```

If I returned a disconnected  *copy* of internal data, or detached result of a data query - I can safely return `List<TItem>` without exposing any of implementation details, and allow to use the returned data in the convenient way.

But this depends on what type of consumer I expect - if this is a something like data grid I prefer to return `IEnumerable<TItem>` *which will be the copied list of items* anyway in most cases :)

Answer (score -1):

Well the Collection class is really just a wrapper class around other collections to hide their implementation details and other features. I reckon this has something to do with the property hiding coding pattern in object-oriented languages.

I think you shouldn't worry about it, but if you really want to please the code analysis tool, just do the following:

```
//using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

Collection<MyClass> myCollection = new Collection<MyClass>(myList);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I menat Collection<MyClass>. I am really looking forward to get my hands on C# 4 and generic covariance btw!

Comment: Wrapping in a `Collection<T>` protects neither itself nor the underlying collection as far as I understand.

Comment: That piece of code was to "please the code analysis tool". I don't think @TamasCzinege said anywhere that using `Collection<T>` will immediately protect your underlying collection.