# Should I return an IEnumerable or IList?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

I wish to return an ordered list of items from a method. Should my return type be IEnumerable or IList?

Comment: I'm still unsure of the answer. Current thinking - not all IEnumerable's guarantee order of elements, hence leaning towards IList.

Comment: Ben, that is not how it works. You already have something ordered (a List) but you expose it as an IEnumerable. That interface won't (can't) change the ordering. Just look at what the receiving end needs, pick the smallest option that fits.

Comment: @Henk - thanks. Say I have the method on an interface and it doesn't make sense for the return value to not be ordered, would you suggest IList or similar then?

Comment: ..currently favouring IOrderedEnumerable (cf mjf196)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I always return IEnumerable<T> instead of IList<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072614/should-i-always-return-ienumerablet-instead-of-ilistt)

Comment: IEnumarble started causing me massive headaches in services that work with IEnumarbales from Repositiories, when I started using `Parallel.` and other threading. My opinion.. IEnumarble should never have been used or passed outside of Data contexts.. unless you are filtering context from yoru front end.. which we all know is bad. So kill IEnumarble and please start using `IList`

Comment: there is a good article on this subject : https://daedtech.com/what-to-return-ienumerable-or-ilist/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a hierarchy here:

```
interface IList<T> : ICollection<T> { } 
interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
```

You want to aim for the least possible coupling, so return an `IEnumerable<T>` if that is enough. It probably will be.

Return an `IList<T>` if the situation requires that the caller gets a List that it can use to Add/Insert/Remove.  But even then it might be better if the caller created his own List from the IEnumerable collection.

Comment: What about functions ElementAt and Count when using IEnumerable? I know each time you call ElementAt, a loop goes throught the entire list until it find the element. This is the same behavior using Count except it loop in the entire list. This should be a consideration to use a list in addition to add, remove and insert. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry but could you expand on least possible coupling? If an IList<T> is an IEnumerable<T> and has advantages like Count, indexing why wouldn't you return it?

Comment: From the producing end, returning just IEnumerable leaves you room pick a different, lighter implementation later. It's more important on the consuming end.

Comment: What about the issue with the IEnumerable is lazy loaded evaluated.

Comment: What about the rule of returning the smallest type?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant smallest as in the most specific type.

Comment: Returning IEnumarable from Respositiores are now causing me problems as I try to parralelise some data crunching and the db context gets recyled while working with IEnum.. I know.. its an implementation thing its not actually lazy loading.. but today, 100% no longer using IEnumarble on any thing, especially that everything along the way always calls ToList() - We all should be using `IList` instead.

Comment: That is an entirely different problem, don't confuse things.

Answer (score 15):

It depends what you want to do with the result. If you need to get the count of items or get random access to individual items, go with an IList.

If callers just want to iterate through the items then go with IEnumerable - **but you should document whether or not the returned value will be evaluated lazily or not** - many IEnumerable instances these days represent queries that will be executed when the collection is enumerated. To be on the safe side, if what you are returning won't be evaluated on demand, I'd go with IList.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing documentation.

Comment: +1 for your first sentence. I just wrote a comment below before reading this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, it's better to return `IEnumerable<T>`, as long as that has everything the caller needs.

`IEnumerable<T>` is foreachable, which is all that's needed for many consumers. It's also read-only, which is often a good thing -- it means you can sometimes optimize by returning your actual backing collection, without worrying too much about someone modifying it without telling you.

However, if the consumer needs methods that aren't on `IEnumerable<T>`, then `IList<T>` might make more sense. For example, the caller may want to call `Contains`, which isn't on `IEnumerable<T>`. Or the caller may want to index into the list, rather than iterating it from start to finish.

But you can do Contains and indexing on `IEnumerable<T>` too, via LINQ's [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) and [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension methods. So there's a question of degree here. If the caller only needs to ask one question that isn't available on `IEnumerable<T>`, like "is this empty", then return an `IEnumerable<T>` and use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) extension method. But if the caller uses `IList<T>` operations extensively, return `IList<T>`.

Comment: By using the LINQ versions of Contains and ElementAt, you maybe can run into performance problems, cause under the hood it just makes a foreach, so it will always be O(n). Depending on the implementation of IList Contains or ElementAt this can be a O(1) operation.

Comment: @Oliver, you're wrong to say "always". The LINQ Contains and ElementAt first try casting the collection to `ICollection<T>` / `IList<T>` so they can call the O(1) method for you. The O(n) implementations are only used if that fails. If you're returning a `List<T>` typed as `IEnumerable<T>`, then Contains and ElementAt are still O(1), though with a bit of extra overhead. You can confirm this in Reflector.

Comment: Thanks for the information, there is still some new to learn. ;-)

Comment: Generally one should also return the smallest/most concrete type which swings towards IList.

Answer (score 5):

Its easy,
if the caller should only use it Readonly, use IEnumerable.
as this is then also supports covariance (result can be casted to a base type)

Comment: It's covariant, actually, but great point.

Comment: interesting point re covariance

Comment: The IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> interface is returned by OrderBy Enumerable extension methods. Its readonly too.

Comment: @mjf. good point. IOrderedEnumerable would be the right one... never used it.

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't guarantee any readonly-ness.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return an ordered list maybe you should return a SortedList.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

You can associate an order with the objects.

Comment: this looks like the answer....

Comment: Can you point me at any information that tells me what .NET collections guarantee ordering?

Comment: True, a sorted list hits by its type, that the result is sorted. but allows manipulation of it. if this is not intended, i would rather go with a ienumerable, and document the sorting in the description.

Comment: This is useful if the client code will need information on the ordering key used.  If not, IEnumerable is preferable in .NET 3.5 or higher (the LINQ extension methods allow all necessary read access, including O(1) Count and indexing.)

Comment: `Count()` and `ElementAt()` are only O(1) for a few special cases - in general they will enumerate the items in the sequence and therefore run in O(n).

Comment: `SortedList<K,V>` is a Dictionary-type collection. There is noting in the OQ indicating that is what is needed.

Comment: OP said "ordered", not "sorted". Ordered means it maintains the original ordering. This is true of the majority of collections, and probably any collection that implements `IList<T>` since that has an indexer. Any collection that doesn't maintain ordering will say so in its documentation, like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` or `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Well, ordering and sorting aren't exactly the same thing.  Its possible to have a list that's ordered, but not sorted.

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerable is less specific than an IList, that is, IList has functions that IEnumerable does not.

Compare the two to see if one has functions you need that the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

An IList has the methods for changing the items (like Add), maybe you want to select between ICollection and IEnumerable.

The ICollection extends IEnumerable and has the Count property available that can be useful.