# Safely combine two ILists, accounting for nulls

Tags: c#

I want to combine two `IList`'s into one, either of which, or both, could be `null`. If both are `null` I want the result to be `null`.

I have this but I want something more elegant but still easy to read.

```
private IList<Filter> CombineFilters(IList<Filter> first, IList<Filter> second)
{
    IList<Filter> result = null;

    if(first != null)
        if (second != null)
            result = first.Concat(second) as IList<Filter>;
        else
            result = first;
    else if (second != null)
        result = second;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Might be better asked on code review, since it appears to be working code. Might I ask why you're trying to avoid assigning `null` to `result` if that turns out to be the correct result anyway (i.e. why the `else if`)?

Comment: You'll need to `first.Concat(second).ToList()` instead of `as IList<Filter>` otherwise result will be null

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the `else if` happens when `first` is `null` and `second` isn't

Comment: @Bobbler - but consider the two cases - either `second` is null or it is not. If `second` is not null, you want the result to be equal to `second`. If `second` is null, you want the result to be null. In either case, no conditional logic is required, and you can just *always* assign `result = second` if `first` turns out to be null.

Comment: Improper usage of the `as` operator. If you would have used a normal cast instead (as you should have), you would have realized that this throws an `InvalidCastException` because the result of a `Concat<T>` is not an `IList<T>`, but a somewhat "smart" iterator type (which also happens to be a read-only interface to the underlying data). You should use normal casts instead of `as` by default, and `as` only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No. Second doesn't take precedence. If both are null I want to return null, or at least an empty List, as others have suggested. If both are non-null I want a concatenation of both.

Comment: I'll try *one more time*. To match your spec, you could simply say "if first is null, I'll return second. If second is null, I'll return first. Only if both are non-null do I need to do anything special." If, in that first case, first was null and you returned second, it *doesn't matter* what value it held, it still matches your spec.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ha! I got it. Thanks for your patience friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think it’s a bit of a weird behavior if I call your `CombineFilters` with two lists (one possibly null) and get back a list which is *not* a copy. That would result in the following behavior:

```
List<Filter> filters1 = new List<Filter>() { new Filter() };
List<Filter> filters2 = null;

Console.WriteLine(filters1.Count); // 1

var filters = CombineFilters(filters1, filters2);
filters.Add(new Filter());

Console.WriteLine(filters.Count); // 2
Console.WriteLine(filters1.Count); // also 2
```

I’m not sure if I would really expect this behavior.

So I would suggest you to always ensure that there will be a *new* list in the end. This allows you to make this really short:

```
private IList<Filter> CombineFilters(IList<Filter> first, IList<Filter> second)
{
    return (first ?? Array.Empty<Filter>()).Concat(second ?? Array.Empty<Filter>()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer. Why is having a new list better? I prefer to only instantiate if necessary.

Comment: It’s not necessarily better but it results in a more consistent experience. Since the method returns an `IList` I would expect to be allowed to modify it; but modifications should probably not end up affecting my original lists. You could avoid this if you would return an `IEnumerable` though, since that is not mutable by design.

Comment: Amazing answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Concate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) together with the `??` operator:

```
if(first == null && second == null)
    return null;
return Enumerable.Concat(first ?? Enumerable.Empty<IFilter>(), 
                         second ?? Enumerable.Empty<IFilter>()).ToList();
```

If either `first` or `second` are `null` a new list will be used instead for the concat.

---

I think that in case both lists are `null` then still an initialize collection should be returned. In that case just remove the if statement. Also maybe return an `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`:

```
private IEnumerable<Filter> CombineFilters(IEnumerable<Filter> first, IEnumerable<Filter> second)
{
    return Enumerable.Concat(first ?? Enumerable.Empty<IFilter>(), 
                             second ?? Enumerable.Empty<IFilter>());
}
```

Returning the `IEnumerable` instead of the `IList` depends on your scenario. Read more here:

- [Should I always return IEnumerable<T> instead of IList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1072614/6400526)
- [Should I return an IEnumerable or IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180658/6400526)

Answer (score 1):

```
private IList<Filter> CombineFilters(IList<Filter> first, IList<Filter> second)
{
    if (first == null && second == null) return null;
    first = first ?? new List<Filter>();
    second = second ?? new List<Filter>();
    return first.Concat(second).ToList();
}
```

Comment: How about `Enumerable.Empty<Filter>()` instead?

Comment: I missed that bit. Seems a bit odd to have a function where the contract is null-is-empty on the input but may return null for the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
private IList<Filter> CombineFilters(IList<Filter> first, IList<Filter> second)
{

    if (first == null && second == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (first ?? Enumerable.Empty<Filter>())
            .Concat(second ?? Enumerable.Empty<Filter>())
            .ToList();
}
```

That said, it's a good practice to avoid null collections entirely; if there are no elements, you just return an empty collection. This way, you don't need to check for null all the time. This may not be possible to do in your case, but if it is, it will make your code quite a bit cleaner.

Also, consider using `IEnumerable<T>` rather then `IList<T>` as it is a more general abstraction (and also because `IList<T>` is a broken, leaky abstraction - implementations throw exceptions (!) for methods they don't support). On the other hand, I can see that this is a private method, and if you are actually always passing `List<Filter>`, it's probably better to declare the parameters as `List<Filter>`.

EDIT:
Just noticed my answer is very similar to the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45688145/8166486) posted by Gilad Green, which I didn't see before.

Comment: How is `IList<T>` leaky?

Comment: @Bobbler: On it's own merits, `IList<T>` is OK, however, in earlier versions of the .NET framework it was treated (more or less) as an abstraction of the notion of a 'collection'. So, many collections in .NET 2.0 implement IList<T>, even though many of them don't support a significant subset of the methods defined by the interface. Their solution was to throw `NotSupportedException`-s, which is pretty horrible. This violates Liskov subtitution principle, and reduces the usefulness of `IList<T>`. Then they figured that collections are really things you can enumerate (`IEnumerable<T>`).