# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, linq-to-entities

I have a method:

```
public DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection GetChildAndOpiekunByFirstnameLastname(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    DataTransfer.ChargeInSchoolEntities db = new DataTransfer.ChargeInSchoolEntities();
    DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection result = new DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection();
    if (firstname == null && lastname != null)
    {
        IList<DzieckoAndOpiekun> resultV = from p in db.Dziecko
                      where lastname == p.Nazwisko
                      **select** new DzieckoAndOpiekun(
                     p.Imie,
                     p.Nazwisko,
                     p.Opiekun.Imie,
                     p.Opiekun.Nazwisko)
                  ;
        result.AddRange(resultV);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and error in selected place :

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WcfService1.DzieckoAndOpiekun>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<WcfService1.DzieckoAndOpiekun>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any idea how solve my problem?

Comment: Related posts : [Convert an IQueryable linq query to IEnumerable<T> cancels out linq optimized way to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14842176/465053) & [Should I always return IEnumerable<T> instead of IList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1072614/465053)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To convert `IQuerable` or `IEnumerable` to a list, you can do one of the following:

```
IQueryable<object> q = ...;
List<object> l = q.ToList();
```

or:

```
IQueryable<object> q = ...;
List<object> l = new List<object>(q);
```

Comment: Of course `.ToArray()` Linq extension could also be used in this case (because a `T[]` is an `IList<T>` as well). But what does the `AddRange` method actually require? Maybe he could just use `var` (which would mean `IQueryable<DzieckoAndOpiekun>` here), and `AddRange` would be happy with that? Note: `IQueryable<>` inherits `IEnumerable<>`.

Answer (score 11):

You can replace `IList<DzieckoAndOpiekun> resultV` with `var resultV`.

Comment: This is a far better answer than the others. Especially if `AddRange()` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` (which it almost certainly would...)

Answer (score 6):

If using a where clause be sure to include `.First()` if you do not want a IQueryable object.

Comment: thanks this helped with a similar problem I was having

Comment: Or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 4):

Try this -->

```
 new DzieckoAndOpiekun(
                         p.Imie,
                         p.Nazwisko,
                         p.Opiekun.Imie,
                         p.Opiekun.Nazwisko).ToList()
```

Comment: .ToList() will work properly what if i am using .Take(2) instead.  It will throw same error

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method to convert the IQueryable result returned to an IList, as shown below, after the linq query.

```
   public DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection GetChildAndOpiekunByFirstnameLastname(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    DataTransfer.ChargeInSchoolEntities db = new DataTransfer.ChargeInSchoolEntities();
    DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection result = new DzieckoAndOpiekunCollection();
    if (firstname == null && lastname != null)
    {
        IList<DzieckoAndOpiekun> resultV = from p in db.Dziecko
                      where lastname == p.Nazwisko
                      **select** new DzieckoAndOpiekun(
                     p.Imie,
                     p.Nazwisko,
                     p.Opiekun.Imie,
                     p.Opiekun.Nazwisko).ToList()
                  ;
        result.AddRange(resultV);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i have then error :Error 1 'WcfService1.DzieckoAndOpiekun' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'WcfService1.DzieckoAndOpiekun' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

I've got solved my problem this way in EF on list of records from db

```
ListOfObjectToBeOrder.OrderBy(x => x.columnName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`SonarQube` reported `Return an empty collection instead of null.` and I had a problem with the error with casting as in the title of this question.
I was able to get rid of both only using `return XYZ.ToList().AsQueryable();` in a method with `IQueryable` like so:

```
public IQueryable<SomeType> MethodName (...) {
  IQueryable<SomeType> XYZ;
  ...
  return XYZ.ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

Hope so it helps for those in a similar scenario(s).

Comment: This is a different case. Almost 100% the reverse. Also, this looks more like bad design. Returning `IQueryable` from a method usually has the purpose of enabling a user to compose on the result. A `List` disguised as an `IQueryable` looks more like a hack than deliberate design.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for the quick feedback, really appreciated!