# Convert an IQueryable linq query to IEnumerable<T> cancels out linq optimized way to work?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm kinda newbie on .NET, and I was wondering how does linq works, since you can aply many linq queries, one after another, but none of them are really executed until they're used to transfer information or converted to list, etc.
There are 2 important ways to get a linq query, by using `IQueryable<T>`, which aplies the where filters directly on the Sql, and IEnumerable which get all the records and then it work with them on memory. However, let's take a look on this code:

```
            //Linq dynamic library
            IQueryable<Table> myResult = db.Categories
                .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(StringName))
                .OrderBy("Name")
                .Skip(0)
                .Take(10);

            if (myResult != null)
            {
                return myResult.AsEnumerable();
            } 
            else
            { return null; }
```

Depsite i'm using Linq dynamic library, the direct result from this query is being get on `IQueryable<T>`, if the query is finally being returned as `IEnumerable`, is the query being really filtered on the sql? or is it in memory?

Comment: I'm sorry, How do i check the log?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's still going to execute in the database, don't worry. Basically it's all down to which implementation of `Where` etc is used. While you're calling methods on `IQueryable<T>` - via the `Queryable` extension methods - it will be using expression trees. When you start to *fetch* from that query, it will be turned into SQL and sent to the database.

On the other hand, if you use any of those methods *after* you've got it as an `IEnumerable<T>` (in terms of the compile-time type), that will use the extension methods in `Enumerable`, and all of the rest of the processing *would* be done in-process.

As an example, consider this:

```
var query = db.People
              .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("J"))
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => x.Age > 20);
```

Here `AsEnumerable()` *just* returns its input sequence, but typed as `IEnumerable<T>`. In this case, the database query would return only people whose name began with `J` - and then the age filtering would be done at the client instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers! they helped a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If you return an `IEnumerable<T>` and then further refine the query, then the further refinement happens in memory. The part that was expressed on an `IQueryable<T>` will get translated to the appropiate SQL statements (for the LINQ-to-SQL case, obviously).

See [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655#2876655) for a longer and more detailed answer.