# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my code which is giving me above error

```
    public ActionResult  Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        KBS_Virtual_TrainingEntities db = new KBS_Virtual_TrainingEntities();
        UsersContext ctx = new UsersContext();
        UserProfile model = ctx.UserProfiles.Find(id);

        List<CourseSubscription> user_Course_subscriptions = new List<CourseSubscription>();



        foreach (UserSubscription sub in db.UserSubscriptions)
        {
            if (sub.ID == id)
            {
                user_Course_subscriptions.Add(sub.CourseSubscription);
            }
        }
        List<CourseSubscription> not_subscribe = db.CourseSubscriptions.Except(user_Course_subscriptions);

        var coursesList = from courses in not_subscribe
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Text = courses.Course.Name,
                              Value = courses.Course.ID
                              .ToString()
                          };
        var CoursesTYPE = from CourseTypes in db.CourseTypes.ToList()
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Text = CourseTypes.Name,
                              Value = CourseTypes.ID
                              .ToString()
                          };

        ViewBag.CourseID = coursesList;
        ViewBag.type = CoursesTYPE;
        return View(model);

    }
```

I am trying to find Course Subscription that are not subscribe by the current user by using the above code but its not working?

Comment: telling at which line of code the exception was thrown exactly may help

Comment: List<CourseSubscription> not_subscribe = db.CourseSubscriptions.Except(user_Course_subscriptions);

Comment: posting complete exact error message also helpful, like this one (possible duplicate btw) : [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402822/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-system-collections-g)

Comment: Error 327 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<KBS_Virtual_Training_Course_Site.CourseSubscription>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KBS_Virtual_Training_Course_Site.CourseSubscription>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)     this error I am getting

Comment: yep, check answer given in the link above. It is almost identical to your problem (only difference is `List<T>` here vs `IList<T>` in the other post). And of course check answer from @McAden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `ToList` on the results from your `Except` function. Do a `ToList` like so:

```
List<CourseSubscription> not_subscribe = db.CourseSubscriptions.Except(user_Course_subscriptions).ToList();
```

Or since in your code you're not doing anything that needs a list, simply `var` it or assign the correct type to it such as `IQueryable<CourseSubscription>` to it.

```
var not_subscribe = db.CourseSubscriptions.Except(user_Course_subscriptions);
```