# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'IList<>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I know questions like this exist, I been through all of them - didn't help.
Here is my class:

```
 public class EventService : IEventService
    {
        TournamentContext db = new TournamentContext();

        public IList<Event> GetEvents()
        {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

            IQueryable<Event> eventsList = from s in db.Event
                         select s;
            events = eventsList.ToList();

            return events;
        }
}
```

I got error:

> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Tournament.Services.Events.IList'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    Tournament.Services

Can't figure out how to convert System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to
'IList<>' tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402822/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-system-collections-g) and few others but it didn't work.

**UPDATE:**

Implementing accepted solution and changing IEventInterface this works just fine now:

```
 public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Event> GetEvents() {

        var events = from s in db.Event
                     select s;

        return events.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you constructing a new list via `List<Event> events = new List<Event>();` only to throw it away and replace it with `events = eventsList.ToList();`?

Comment: Is there any chance you used some refactoring tool and accidentally created a class `IList<T>` yourself?  This should work, and your error message doesn't show a fully qualified name for `IList<T>`

Comment: @roryap Well I tried to implement what is suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402822/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-system-collections-g

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I've added full error. I am using Unity.

Comment: Pretty much what I said.  You're using the wrong `IList`.

Comment: `public  System.Collections.Generic.IList<Event> GetEvents()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman what are you referring to?  Calling the `List<Event>` constructor is harmless?  How do you know there's no overhead?

Comment: @MikeDebela yes - that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code or in a DLL you referenced you created a `Tournament.Services.Events.IList<T>` interface or class, your code when you do

```
public IList<Event> GetEvents()
```

is actually doing

```
public Tournament.Services.Events.IList<Event> GetEvents()
```

The `List<T>` built in to .NET does not support your interface, you need to use the `IList<T>` that came with .NET. Make your function

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Event> GetEvents()
```

and that should fix it for now, however I really recommend you rename or delete the `IList` in the `Tournament.Services.Events` namespace to prevent this problem in the future.

Comment: I've replaced it in other functions and IEventService as well - works now! :)