# IEnumerable & Good Practices (& WCF)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ienumerable

Is it a good practice to use `IEnumerable` application-wide whenever you don't need to actually *add* or *remove* things but only enumerate them?

*Side question:* Did you ever have any problems returning `IEnumerable<T>` from a WCF service? Can that cause problems to client applications? After all, I think that will be serialized to an array.

Comment: Perhaps you should add what language you are talking about? This is not a .net-only site, after all...

Comment: While this is **not an exact duplicate**, I still suggest you have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072614/should-i-always-return-ienumerablet-instead-of-ilistt

Answer (score 13):

I tend to only return `IEnumerable<T>` when I want to hint to the caller that the implementation may use lazy evaluation.  Otherwise, I'd usually return `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, and implement as a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` if the result should be readonly.

Lazy evaluation can be an important consideration: if your implementation can throw an exception, this won't be thrown until the caller starts enumerating the result.  By returning `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, you're guaranteeing that any exception will be thrown at the point the method is called.

In the case of a WCF method, returning `IEnumerable<T>` from a method that uses lazy evaluation means any exception might not be thrown until your response is being serialized - giving you less opportunity to handle it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any Good Practices sources, but i often tend to rely on List for my collections and it implements IEnumerable but i do pass it around as a List and not a IEnumerable, if i need it to be read only i rather pass a ReadOnlyCollection..

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to return or accept `IList<T>` or `List<T>` because they implies the ability to modify a collection.

So prefer to return `T[]` as fixed-sized collection. Also array can be easily mapped to any other framework, platform, etc.

And prefer to accept `IEnumerable<T>` to emphasize that a method will enumerate that collection.

Comment: T[] is not a read-only collection: you can modify the elements of an array.  Conversely, IList<T> does not imply the ability to modify a collection - e.g. IList<T>.IsReadOnly is true for ReadOnlyCollection<T>.  If it's important that callers don't modify the returned collection, it's probably best to return IList<T> and implement as a ReadOnlyCollection<T> of immutable objects.