# Linq-to-SQL ToList() With/without records?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Tried to look for this question on SO, but couldn't find it.

**What's the best way to return a list of records from a static method?**

**I want to return either an empty list or a populated list from my static method.**

Given the following method:

```
    public static List<division> GetAllDivisions(bool isAvailable)
    {
        MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ();
        List<division> DivisionList = new List<division>();

        var data = from d in db.divisions
                   where d.isAvailable == isAvailable
                   select d;

        if(data.Count() > 0)
            DivisionList = data.ToList();

        return DivisionList;
    }
```

Do I really need to do the following?

```
 if(data.Count() > 0)
      DivisionList = data.ToList();
```

Can I just do `DivisionList = data.ToList()` without checking the count?

I want to be able to return either a populated list or an empty list - **and I don't want an error thrown if there are 0 records.**

What are best practices? Is it better to return `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to return either a populated list or an empty list -
>   and I don't want an error thrown if there are 0 records.

You don't have to check for `Count`, `ToList` would not return a `null`, it could return an empty list, which you are trying to do with your check. Simply `data.ToList();` is enough. It will return list with records or an empty list, but not null.

You can do:

```
public static List<division> GetAllDivisions(bool isAvailable)
{
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    return db.divisions
             .Where(d => d.isAvailable == isAvailable)
             .ToList();
}
```

For

> Is it better to return IEnumerable?

See: [Should I always return IEnumerable<T> instead of IList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072614/should-i-always-return-ienumerablet-instead-of-ilistt)