# Grouping list elements to dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains 8 elements:

```
ConfigFile.ControllerList
```

this list is type of:

```
List<Controller>
```

How can i add Controllers from ControllerList to 3 dictionary keys. Dictionary is like:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Controller>> ControllerDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Controller>>();
```

I want to add first 3 controllers to dictionary key 0, then want to add next 3 controllers to dictionary key 1 and lastly want to add last 2 controllers to dictionary key 2. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/` to split the list into sub-list:

```
var ControllerDictionary = ControllerList
    .Select((c, i) => new { Controller = c, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / maxGroupSize)
    .Select((g, i) => new { GroupIndex = i, Group = g })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.GroupIndex, x => x.Group.Select(xx => xx.Controller).ToList());
```

The idea is to first group the elements by indexes, then divide them by an `int` maxGroupSize(in your case 3). Then convert each group to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a more elegant solution, but something like this should work:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<Controller>>();

int x = 0;
while (x < controllerList.Count)
{
   var newList = new List<Controller> { controllerList[x++] };

   for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) // execute twice
      if (x < controllerList.Count)
         newList.Add(controllerList[x++]);

   dict.Add(dict.Count, newList);
}
```

To make it more general, you could also create `newList` empty to start, and then change `y < 2` to `y < GROUP_SIZE` where `GROUP_SIZE` is whatever sized groups you want. Could even then extract this to an extension method:

```
public static Dictionary<int, List<T>> ToGroupedDictionary<T>
   (this IList<T> pList, int pGroupSize)
{
   var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>();

   int x = 0;
   while (x < pList.Count)
   {
      var newList = new List<T>();

      for (int y = 0; y < pGroupSize && x < pList.Count; y++, x++)
         newList.Add(pList[x]);

      dict.Add(dict.Count, newList);
   }

   return dict;
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
var groups = new[]
{
   "Item1",
   "Item2",
   "Item3",
   "Item4",
   "Item5",
   "Item6",
   "Item7",
   "Item8"
}.ToGroupedDictionary(3);
```

Comment: You are confusing `dictKey` with the index into `list`…