# Using BindableCollection outside ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In our team during Code Review I see something strange. One of our developer create class to read data from file. In this class he create method to return this data to ViewModel. He use BindableCollection (from Caliburn.Micro) as return type.

```
public BindableCollection<T> GetData()
{
//read data
}
```

But I think that is a bad practice beacuse BindableCollection is a collection to work with ViewModel not with model. I write code looking like this:

```
public List<T> GetData()
{
//read data
}
```

Of course in ViewModel he write `Items=new model.GetData()` and he think that is better than mine `Items.AddRange(new model.GetData())`. Result is the same. 
I think his code break SOLID rule. Is any other good reason to change this code?

Comment: [ienumerablet as return type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/381218/968303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe *ObservableCollection* is what you are looking for ? You can bind it to a view with CollectionChanged Events and so on.

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

And i dont know the Caliburn.Micro BindableCollection but mainly you should use an IObserable inheriting collection in ViewModel and an IList or ICollection in model.

When your ViewModel is loading data, you cann easily create an ObservableCollection with an IList or ICollection by constructor.

I Hope this helps.

```cs
var myObservableList = new ObservableCollection<MyModelType>(myModel.NiceList);
```

Comment: BindableCollection  inherit from ObservableCollection.

Comment: Okay.But i think this should be a normal usecase. It depends on what are you going to do with your collection. ObservableCollection is used to bind to a view. And an IList or ICollection is used to hold data.

Comment: I want load data from file on window load

Comment: maybe your solution with AddRange() is faster then the solution of your teammember

Comment: @wopi ... do you use TwoWay Bindings in View ? If not you do not Need an ObservableCollection

Comment: I use TwoWay Binding. And I must use BindableCollection in ViewModel

Comment: Okay so then you should use List<T> GetItems() and in your ViewModel you use BindableCollection<T> and use AddRange() or new BinableCollection<T>(model.GetItems()).