# What is the difference between List (of T) and Collection(of T)?

Tags: .net, list, collections

I've seen them used in a lot of the same ways, and I am worried I'm about to go down a path in design that is irreversible if I don't understand this better. Also, I am using .NET.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Collection<T>` is a customizable wrapper around `IList<T>`. While `IList<T>` is not sealed, it doesn't provide any customization points. `Collection<T>`'s methods are by default delegated to the standard `IList<T>` methods, but can be easily overridden to do what you want. It is also possible to wireup events inside a `Collection<T>` that I don't believe could be done with an IList.

In short, it's much easier to extend it after the fact, which could potentially mean a lot less refactoring.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, @Adam Lassek: Can't we do the same thing with a List by hiding the InsertItem(...) method with a public void new InsertItem(...) and then calling the base.InsertItem(...) from within ? It would still not break the contract. (the name is 'Insert' in List, but nonetheless). So what is the big deal in sticking to Collections<T> ?

Comment: @DeeStackOverflow - because method hiding won't be used by any code that uses a different API - i.e. Anything that looks for `IList`, `IList<T>`, `List<T>` etc. In short, you have no idea whether it will be called. Polymorphism fixes this.

Comment: @AdamLassek: You might want to add in your answer about `ObservableCollection<T>` as an example where methods are overriden to notify about changes.

Answer (score 118):

In C#, there are three concepts for representing a bag of objects. In order of increasing features, they are:

- **Enumerable** - unordered, unmodifiable
- **Collection** - can add/remove items
- **List** - allows items to have an order (accessing and removing by index)

**Enumerable** has no order. You cannot add or remove items from the set. You cannot even get a count of items in the set. It strictly lets you access each item in the set, one after the other.

**Collection** is a modifiable set. You can add and remove objects from the set, you can also get the count of items in the set. But there still is no order, and because there is no order: no way to access an item by index, nor is there any way to sort.

**List** is an ordered set of objects. You can sort the list, access items by index, remove items by index.

In fact, when looking at the interfaces for these, they build on one another:

- `interface IEnumerable<T>`

  - `GetEnumeration<T>`
- `interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>`

  - `Add`
  - `Remove`
  - `Clear`
  - `Count`
- `interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>`

  - `Insert`
  - `IndexOf`
  - `RemoveAt`

When declaring variables, or method parameters, you should choose to use

- IEnumerable
- ICollection
- IList

based on what conceptually you need to do with the set of objects.

If you just need to be able to do something to every object in a list, then you only need `IEnumerable`:

```
void SaveEveryUser(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    for User u in users
      ...
}
```

You don't care if the Users are kept in a `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, `Array<T>` or anything else. You only need the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

If you need to be able to add, remove, or count the items in a set, then use a **Collection**:

```
ICollection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
users.Add(new User());
```

If you care about a sort order, and need the order to be correct, then use a **List**:

```
IList<User> users = FetchUsers(db);
```

In chart form:

```
| Feature                | IEnumerable<T> | ICollection<T> | IList<T> |
|------------------------|----------------|----------------|----------|
| Enumerating items      | X              | X              | X        |
|                        |                |                |          |
| Adding items           |                | X              | X        |
| Removing items         |                | X              | X        |
| Count of items         |                | X              | X        |
|                        |                |                |          |
| Accessing by index     |                |                | X        |
| Removing by index      |                |                | X        |
| Getting index of item  |                |                | X        |
```

The `List<T>` and `Collection<T>` in `System.Collections.Generic` are two classes that implement these interfaces; but they aren't the only classes:

- [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) is an ordered bag of objects (`IEnumerable<T>`)
- [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) is a bag where you are not allowed to access items by index (`ICollection`); but you can arbitrarily add and remove items from the collection
- [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx) is an ordered collection, where you can add/remove items by index

So you can easily change:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = new SynchronizedCollection<User>();

SaveEveryUser(users);
```

## tl;dr

- **Enumerable** - access items, unordered, unmodifiable
- **Collection** - can be modified (add,delete,count)
- **List** - can access by index

Choose the *concept* you need, then use the matching class.

Comment: The OP asked about the concrete types, and you've compared the Interfaces. The concrete type Collection<T> implements IList<T> and has accessing by index capabilities.

Comment: The answer is good but deviated from the question.Can't fit your answer for Collection<T> and List<T> classes, I mean from question prospective if I try to validated your point they just don't justify. For a general purpose answer you may be right that collection is not ordered so no indexing, but list is ordered so insertion is possible at a certain index.

Comment: If the list is ordered and the collection is orderless, that would be a huge functional difference to easily guide a new learner (like me) to choose. But wait, why do you say a collection has no order? It provides [IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RemoveAt()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414(v=vs.110).aspx) method, so it IS ordered, isn't it? Did I miss something here?

Comment: @RayLuo I'm referring specifically to `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`. Different concrete implementations may behave differently. For example if you access a `List<T>` through its `IEnumerable<T>` interface, then you have no way to add, remove, sort, or count items in the list.

Comment: This answer was very helpful! Deviated from the question a bit, but this was what I was trying to search for.

Answer (score 44):

`List<T>` is intended for internal use within the application code. You should avoid writing public APIs that accept or return `List<T>` (consider using a superclass or a collection interface instead).

`Collection<T>` serves a base class for custom collections (although it can be used directly).

Consider using `Collection<T>` in your code unless there are specific features of `List<T>` that you need.

The above are just recommendations.

[Adapted from: Framework Design Guidelines, Second Edition]

Comment: It's worth noting that types which use *any* kind of mutable objects to encapsulate *their own* state should avoid returning objects of such type unless either the objects in question have a means of notifying their owner when they are mutated, or the name of the method returning the object clearly implies that it is returning a new instance.  Note that for e.g. a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to return `List<string>` is just fine, since the dictionary's state only encapsulates the *identities* of the lists therein, rather than their contents.

Answer (score 37):

`List<T>` is a very commonly seen container, because it is so very versatile (with lots of handy methods like `Sort`, `Find`, etc) - but has no extension points if you want to override any of the behaviour (check items on insert, for example).

`Collection<T>` is a wrapper around any `IList<T>` (defaulting to `List<T>`) - it has the extension points (`virtual` methods), but not as many support methods like `Find`. Because of the indirection, it is slightly slower than `List<T>`, but not by much.

With LINQ, the extra methods in `List<T>` become less important, since LINQ-to-Objects tends to provide them anyway... for example `First(pred)`, `OrderBy(...)`, etc.

Comment: Collection<T> lacks method foreach, even in Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: @tuinstoel - but it is trivial to add.

Answer (score 12):

List is faster.

Do for example

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Collection<long> c = new Collection<long>();
  Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
  s.Start();
  for (long i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++)
  {
    c.Add(i);
  }
  s.Stop();
  MessageBox.Show("collect " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

  List<long> l = new List<long>();
  Stopwatch s2 = new Stopwatch();
  s2.Start();
  for (long i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++)
  {
    l.Add(i);
  }
  s2.Stop();
  MessageBox.Show("lis " + s2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());


}
```

on my machine `List<>` is almost twice as fast.

**Edit**

I can't understand why people are downvoting this. Both on my work machine and my home machine the List<> code is 80% faster.

Comment: How is it faster? Lookup? Insertion? Removal? Search? Why is it faster?

Comment: List is fewer letters to type than Collection :)

Comment: Collection has fewer methods. Therefore it's faster. QED. (joking, I'm not trolling)

Comment: Tried it on my machine and list is about 20% faster. Would be interested in some discussion on why this might be. Maybe the list is better with allocating memory.

Comment: On my machine list is 30% faster.

Comment: List's methods aren't inheritable so there aren't checks to see if they have been inherited; Collection's methods are inheritable.  The advantage is that you can use Collection as a base class to inherit from and create a custom Collection.

Comment: Just wanted to double check -- these tests are release mode compiled, right? My only guess for the speed difference would be that there's fewer method lookups since there isn't an override path to follow. (not `virtual` in `List<T>`)

Comment: Collection uses IList to store the data. if the constructor does not provide a specific IList, Collection uses List. Therefore, List is always faster than Collection.

Answer (score 11):

List represents a collection where the order of items is important. It also supports methods s.a. Sort and search. Collection is a more general data-structure which makes less assumptions about the data and also supports less methods to manipulate it. If you want to expose a custom data structure, you should probably extend the collection. If you need to manipulate data w/o exposing the data-structure, a list is probably the more convenient way to go.

Answer (score 6):

All of these interfaces inherit from `IEnumerable`, which you should make sure you understand. That interface basically lets you use the class in a foreach statement (in C#).

- `ICollection` is the most basic of the interfaces you listed. It's an enumerable interface that supports a `Count` and that's about it.
- `IList` is everything that `ICollection` is, but it also supports adding and removing items, retrieving items by index, etc. It's the most commonly-used interface for "lists of objects", which is vague I know.
- `IQueryable` is an enumerable interface that supports LINQ. You can always create an `IQueryable` from an IList and use LINQ to Objects, but you also find `IQueryable` used for deferred execution of SQL statements in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities.
- `IDictionary` is a different animal in the sense that it is a mapping of unique keys to values. It is also enumerable in that you can enumerate the key/value pairs, but otherwise it serves a different purpose than the others you listed

Comment: ICollection supports adding/removing/clearing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those grad school questions.  A Collection of T is sort of abstract; there may be a default implementation (I'm not a .net/c# guy) but a collection will have basic operations like add, remove, iterate, and so on.

List of T implies some specifics about these operations: add should take constant time, remove should take time proportional to the number of elements, getfirst should be consant time.  In general, a List is a kind of Collection, but a Collection isn't necessarily a kind of List.

Answer (score 4):

[Hanselman Speaks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=4bfad15c-0e56-4902-a603-39afe094bfdf): "`Collection<T>` looks like a list, and it even has a `List<T>` internally.  EVERY single method delegates to the internal `List<T>`.  It includes a protected property that exposes the `List<T>`."

EDIT:  `Collection<T>` doesn't exist in System.Generic.Collections .NET 3.5.  If you migrate from .NET 2.0 to 3.5 you'll need to change some code if you're using a lot of `Collection<T>` objects, unless I'm missing something obvious...

EDIT 2: `Collection<T>` is now in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace in .NET 3.5.  The help file says this:

"The System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace contains classes that can be used as collections in the object model of a reusable library. Use these classes when properties or methods return collections."

Answer (score 4):

According to MSDN, List(Of T).Add is "an O(n) operation" (when "Capacity" is exceeded) while Collection(Of T).Add is *always* "an O(1) operation".  That would understandable if List is implemented using an Array and Collection a Linked List.  However, if that were the case, one would expect Collection(Of T).Item to be "an O(n) operation".  But - it's - *not*!?!  Collection(Of T).Item is "an O(1) operation" just like List(Of T).Item.

On top of that, "tuinstoel"'s "Dec 29 '08 at 22:31" post above claims speed tests show List(Of T).Add to be faster than Collection(Of T).Add which I've reproduced with Long's and String's.  Although I only got ~33% faster vs. his claimed 80%, according MSDN, it should've been the opposite and by "n" times!?!

Answer (score 3):

Both implement the same interfaces, so they'll behave the same way.  Perhaps they are implemented differently internally, but this would have to be tested.

The only real differences I see are the namespaces and the fact that `Collection<T>` is marked with `ComVisibleAttribute(false)`, so COM code can't use it.

Comment: They implement different interfaces - List<T> implements IList<T>, where Collection<T> does not.

Comment: @Bevan try it in c#, they both implement same set of interfaces

Comment: That's an interesting change @KyloRen - they **do** now both implement the same set of interfaces; this wasn't the case back in '08.

Comment: @Bevan interesting. Not sure what was the reason of two different classes, one with just some extra methods.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other asnwers, I've compiled quick overview of generic list and collection capabilities. Collection is limited subset of the List:

```
* = present
o = partially present

Property/Method   Collection<T>   List<T>
----------------------------------------------
Add()                *              *
AddRange()                          *
AsReadOnly()                        *
BinarySearch()                      *
Capacity                            *
Clear()              *              *
Contains()           *              *
ConvertAll()                        *
CopyTo()             o              *
Count                *              *
Equals()             *              *
Exists()                            *
Find()                              *
FindAll()                           *
FindIndex()                         *
FindLast()                          *
FindLastIndex()                     *
ForEach()                           *
GetEnumerator()      *              *
GetHashCode()        *              *
GetRange()                          *
GetType()            *              *
IndexOf()            o              *
Insert()             *              *
InsertRange()                       *
Item()               *              *
LastIndexOf()                       *
New()                o              *
ReferenceEquals()    *              *
Remove()             *              *
RemoveAll()                         *
RemoveAt()           *              *
RemoveRange()                       *
Reverse()                           *
Sort()                              *
ToArray()                           *
ToString()           *              *
TrimExcess()                        *
TrueForAll()                        *
```