# when to use Collection<T> vs List<T>

Tags: .net, list, collections, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between List (of T) and Collection(of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t)

What is the best practice for when to use one vs the other?

Both implement IList<T> and hold the data in an ordered fashion, but only List expose the sorting semantics....

Comment: ach.. I searched for this topic before I asked, but didn't find the duplicate. Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 25):

- [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx):

  > Provides the base class for a generic
  >   collection.
- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

  > Represents a strongly typed list of
  >   objects that can be accessed by index.
  >   Provides methods to search, sort, and
  >   manipulate lists.

So, according the docs, one is intended as a base class for collections. The other is intended for use as a container.

So **use** `List<T>` and **inherit** from `Collection<T>`.

Comment: Btw, `Collection<T>` implements the interface `IList<T>` and has a `List<T>` inside its implementation.  (It's a facade wrapper class.)