# ICollection property and encapsulation

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Is it bad practice to use interfaces for my properties considering I want to encapsulate them?

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly ICollection<OrderItem> _orderItems;
    public IReadOnlyCollection OrderItems => _orderItems; // not possible without ToList
}
```

There's no easy way to expose it as there's no way to convert to `IReadOnlyCollection` or `IEnumerable` from `ICollection` without using `ToList` first which involves copying entire collection.

Should I define it as:

```
private readonly Collection<OrderItem> _orderItems;
```

or

```
private readonly HashSet<OrderItem> _orderItems;
```

or

```
private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems;
```

instead?

Comment: Always use the lowest possible denominator. i.e. for parameters in methods or constructors use `IEnmuerable<T>` unless you require something from more specialized interfaces, i.e. `.Count` or need `Add/Remove` methods etc. As return time, the lowest common and depending on your intention. Do you want people to change the result? use `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` Don't want user to manipulate it? `IEnumerable<T>` and it may be iterable (i.e. not executed immediately). Or return `T[]` if it should be more explicit that its an array and not any general enumerable/iterator

Comment: @Tseng yeah the question here was more about using `ICollection` in private fields in order to later expose it as `IReadOnlyCollection`. Other than that I usually do as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you should follow is that private members are only visible to the class where they are defined so you can define the type as `List<T>` or `Hashset<T>` or `Collection<T>`, other developpers that use your class's assembly will not be impacted by a breaking changes if you modify the type later.

You can choose one of the three alternatives you put in your question as long as long you know the difference between [`Hasset<T>` vs `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt) and [`List<T>` vs `Collection<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419914/when-to-use-collectiont-vs-listt).

So remove the interface `ICollection<OrderItem>` as a type of your **private** field and use a concrete class if you don't want to call `ToList()` in `OrderItems` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension to convert ICollection to IReadOnlyCollection

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly<T>(this ICollection<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        return source as IReadOnlyCollection<T> ?? new ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter<T>(source);
    }
    sealed class ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>
    {
        ICollection<T> source;
        public ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter(ICollection<T> source) { this.source = source; }
        public int Count { get { return source.Count; } }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return source.GetEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: ToList (that return an IReadOnlyCollection) is already an extension method. So I don't know why you need another extension method?

Comment: I think it's too hackish and it's a code smell to do such thing.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, ToList involves copying entire collection and it solves more generic task, while this extension is focused only on providing IReadOnlyCollection