# What is the most basic class that inherits ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, icollection

I need a generic collection class which I can add to, and enumerate over.  Since `ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, the class really just needs to inherit from `ICollection<T>`.  Is there a simple generic class in the BCL that just inherits `ICollection<T>` like a generic version of CollectionBase? If not, then what class comes closest?

I would guess `List<T>` which is what I've been using but i don't need to sequential aspect. Is there anything better (by which I mean [smaller memory footprint/faster access/simpler])?  Bag would be perfect if it existed.

**EDIT 1:** In my particular instance, I'm `.concat`ing to another IEnumerable, querying it, and then displaying the results (in no particular order).  I'm not attempting to make my own class.  I've just needed to make a throwaway collection so many times, that I thought it would be useful to find the best throwaway to use.  Because I feel I've done something similar so many times, I felt I should keep this question as generic as possible (no pun intended), I know better now.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks for everybody's answers, As @BlueRaja pointed out, any simple class is going to have about the same overhead, and thus I think I will be sticking with my original ways of using `List<T>`.  Since they are all about the same, my silly reasons of "It's easier to type", and "I don't have to bring in yet another using" aren't such bad reasons.

Comment: Sounds to me as you want the sequential aspect after all, since you're concatenating it with another enumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [smaller memory footprint/faster access/simpler]

They are all going to have pretty much the same memory footprint, and if you use ICollection the interface will not change.

What really matters is which will scale best for the operations you need:  Linked-list does better appending/removal (of head/tail elements), while an array-based list has random-access.  There are other structures too - which you should use depends on your application.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say they all have the same memory footprint.  A linked list will use more memory than an array-based list.  As you note, it definitely performs better for insertions and removals at the ends.  This can apply in the middle too, if you already have a LinkedListNode pointer (sometimes regardless).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).  It was designed for the express purpose of subclassing, as the documentation indicates:

> Provides the base class for a generic collection.

Having said that, any of the collections are fine; I've inherited from `List<T>`, `Stack<T>` and so on; pick whichever one is closest to the functionality you actually need.

Comment: By default `Collection<T>` uses a `List<T>` as it's backing store so it's not smaller/faster than `List<T>` but exactly the opposite--it's an additional layer of abstraction (not that it would make a measurable difference).

Comment: This might be of some relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426182/what-is-the-real-advantage-of-returning-icollectiont-instead-of-a-listt-clo

Comment: @Sam: By default, yes, but you can use anything as the backing store.  That's why they introduced it; so you could design collection classes without having to concern yourself about what kind of backing storage is used, to avoid coupling yourself to a specific implementation.

Comment: @Igor: I don't really see how that link is relevant.  That's about returning abstract interface types from methods instead of the internally-used concrete types.

Comment: Like @Sam said, `List<T>` is smaller.  I'm not looking to subclass, only to hold a collection.  It does seem strange that `Collection<T>` is larger than `List<T>`

Comment: @Martin: You and Sam are both missing the point; it's not about being "larger" or "smaller", the overhead is so minuscule that it's not going to make any difference in practice.  What *will* make a difference is if you decide 3 months down the road that you picked an implementation that was inefficient for your particular usage pattern; if that happens, your life will be a lot easier if you used a more abstract type like `Collection<T>` than if you used a highly-specific type like `List<T>`.  You should only pick `List<T>` if you know that it's optimal for your requirements.

Comment: Stick with List<T>. See the list and description in this link. I really dont think you have anything smaller than List<T> to pick from. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Not to mention... your question literally asked if there was a "generic version of `CollectionBase`."  Well, this is it.  `CollectionBase` uses an `ArrayList` as its internal storage.  `Collection<T>` uses `List<T>` by default, the generic equivalent of `ArrayList`.  `Collection<T>` is, in all meaningful respects, the generic equivalent of `CollectionBase`.  That is the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @Martin, instead of using `Collection<T>` because it provides some abstraction it would be even better to program to the interfaces everywhere except when the collections are created, then it's trivial to choose a different implementation since everything else uses the interface.

Comment: @Sam, yes, that's what I've been doing and is great advice, and my OP really meant to pertain to the trivial choice of implementation, which I'm realizing now that `List<T>` is as good as any.

@Aaronaught, Thank-you for your answer, it truely was helpful even if not exactly what I needed.  Indeed `Collection<T>` does seem the generic equivalent to `CollectionBase`.  Had I known about `Collection<T>` I would have phrased my question a bit differently and placed more emphasis on only inheriting from ICollection<T>.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller and faster all depends on what exactly you're doing and what your needs are.  The only other class I might recommend is `LinkedList<>` which implements `ICollection<>`.

Comment: In my particular instance, I'm `concat`ing it onto another `IEnumerable`, querying that `IEnumerable` and displaying the output.  `LinkedList<>` looks like it has even more structure than List.

Comment: @Martin: "more structure" does not mean "slower" or "greater memory footprint."  Even if you have 1,000,000 items in each list, you will still only have **two** lists, so the memory-overhead of the lists themselves is not of great importance.

Comment: @Martin Neal, those are the kind of details that would be helpful to include in the original question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to check the .NET FCL and see what classes use that collection. (There is a search feature that can be started by F3.)

You can also take a look at the [C5 Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) to see if a collection has already been implemented that meets your needs. Check out page 13 of the [C5 Manual](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/ITU-TR-2006-76.pdf) for the collection interface hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionBase` existed primarily to provide a simple mechanism to create typed collections.  With Generics, all collections are now typed.  The vast majority of cases where extensions of `CollectionBase` used to be used should now be using any of the built-in collections such as `List<>` or `LinkedList<>`.

`Collection<>` still exists for those that need to provide a custom collection for reasons other than type (i.e., extra validation on add, or some non-standard logic).  `Collection<>` is not nearly as commonly used as `CollectionBase` was and serves a much smaller need.