# c# Extend base class' method

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do this:

```
class BetList : List<Bet>
{
    public uint Sum { get; private set; }
    void Add(Bet bet) : base.Add(bet)  // <-- I mean this
    {
        Sum += bet.Amount;
    } 
}
```

I want to use the base List class to do the List operation. I'd like to implement the Summming only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about calculating the sum on-the-fly when you need it instead of storing it ?

```
class BetList : List<Bet>
{
    public uint Sum 
    { 
        get { return this.Count > 0 ? this.Sum(bet => bet.Amount) : 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit check for an empty sequence; [`Sum` will return 0 in that case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb535184.aspx).

Comment: @shambulator That's correct, but I'm a strong fan of absolutely failsafe code no matter what

Comment: I'll clarify: it's *documented* to return 0 in that case. I don't know what failure your check is guaranteeing against :)

Answer (score 6):

you should use composition, instead of derivation

```
class BetList
{
     List<Bet> _internalList=new List<Bet>();
     //forward all your related operations to _internalList;
}
```

Comment: Additionally you can implement `IEnumerable<Bet>` or `IList<Bet>` if you would like to use the class either of those ways, without having to subclass `List<T>`.

Comment: Well, 'alternatively' would mean instead of your answer. I mean 'additionally' because it is compatible with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to extend an existing collection type you should use `Collection<T>` which is designed for this purpose.  For example:

```
public class BetList : Collection<Bet>
{
    public uint Sum { get; private set; }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        Sum = 0;
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Bet item)
    {
        Sum += item.Amount;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        Sum -= item.Amount;
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, Bet item)
    {
        Sum -= this[i].Amount;
        Sum += item.Amount;
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

A good explanation of the differences between `List<T>` and `Collection<T>` can be found here: [What is the difference between List (of T) and Collection(of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t)

The above class would be used like this:

```
var list = new BetList();
list.Add( bet );  // this will cause InsertItem to be called
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the class derivation instead of composition, try this:

```
class BetList : List<Bet>
{
    public uint Sum { get; private set; }
    new void Add(Bet bet) 
    {
        base.Add(bet);
        Sum += bet.Amount;
    } 
}
```

Comment: And then someone passes `BetList` to a method taking `List<Bet>` and oh look we're of to hell in a hand-basket! There is _(almost)_ **never** a good reason for doing this, and this is not one of those reasons.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier to be fair, this is the only answer that directly answers the actual question, (although I'm not sure what the policy is about what to do when someone asks how to do something they probably shouldn't do).

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Can you explain the problem (in more details) with this solution? Since my main post I noticed that List<> has a Sum method but except that I still don't understand why this solution is problematic.