# Microsoft.visualbasic.collection has no type parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

When I tried to add this property in one of class file i'm getting error.

```
Friend Property StatusesCollection() As New Collection(Of Status)
```

In this the status is a collection of properties.The error is thrown in the `Status`.

Error:

```
 Microsoft.visualbasic.collection has no type parameters an so cannot have type arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

Comment: For reference the `Collections.ObjectModel` has a zero-based index, compared to the usual Collection that has a 1-based index So it might not be a drop in replacement depending on if indexes is used or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your project which contains a `Collection` class. This is what the compiler thinks you are trying to use and throws your error because it is not a generic type.

However what you are trying to use is the Generic Collection object `Collection(Of T)` which is in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace.

Easiest solution is to reference the fully qualified name so that the class is no longer ambiguous. Change:

```
Friend Property StatusesCollection() As New Collection(Of Status)
```

to

```
Friend Property StatusesCollection() As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Status)
```

Or use a `List(Of T)` instead:

```
Friend Property StatusesCollection() As New List(Of Status)
```

See this question for a comparison: [What is the difference between List (of T) and Collection(of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t)