# OK to return an internal List<T> as an IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, collections, return, return-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collection<T> versus List<T> what should you use on your interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271710/collectiont-versus-listt-what-should-you-use-on-your-interfaces)

Consider this method—the returned variable `myVar` is a `List<T>`, but the return type of the method `MyMethod()` is an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> MyMethod(string stuff)
{
     var myVar = new List<T>();
     //do stuff

     return myVar;
}
```

Essentially, what I want to know is if returning `myVar` as a different type is OK.

Specifically, with respect to my situation, the 'do stuff' goes through a `DataRow` and assigns the items in that `DataRow` to a list of objects. I also have similar situations with `ICollection` and `IList` return types in other places.

The reason I want to return either `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` is so that I'm not returning more than needed. But at the same time, this allows the caller to convert the returned value to a `List` if it needs to do so.

However, it seems weird that my return statement is returning a `List`, instead of what the method's return type is. Is this normal practice? Is there anything wrong with doing this?

**Clarification (in response to the dupe comments):**

Just to clarify, what I'm curious about is if it is okay that my return statement in the body is returning a `List<T>`, but the method header has a return-type of `IEnumerable`, or possibly `ICollection`, `Collection`, etc... Something *different* than than bodies return statement.

Comment: The caller shouldn't ever convert from IEnumerable to List. The reason it is returning an interface is because it shouldn't matter if there is an underlying list, oberveable collection, simple array or even a list via yield return.

Comment: The two suggested dupes are closer to dupes of each other than this question to them, I think, although they're all closely related.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk I agree that this question is not a duplicate and I have reworked it to hopefully better convey what I believe makes it unique. I have also voted to to reopen the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only there's nothing wrong with it, but it's actually good practice: expose only what is strictly necessary. That way, the caller can't rely on the fact that the method will return a `List<T>`, so if for some reason you need to change the implementation to return something else, you won't break your contract. However the calling code *might* break if it (incorrectly) made assumptions about what the method actually returns.

Comment: "....and the caller can convert it to a List if it needs" sounds that this is already intended, still good practise?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, well, if the caller is *supposed* to know that the method returns a List, then the return type should be List, of course... It's not even a matter of good practice, just a matter of common sense ;)

Comment: So then to verify, my return statement returns a List<T>, but the method's return type is IEnumerable<T>, this is okay?

Comment: @Tonnie, yes, this is fine, unless you need the caller to know that it's a list

Comment: [Code Analysis (and FxCop)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271710/1497596) advises that when returning a concrete generic collection, one of the following should be returned: `Collection<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `KeyedCollection<T>`. And that `List<T>` should *not* be returned. In the OP's case, returning `IList<T>` will allow indexing into the returned collection. And returning `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` will return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (which also allows retrieving an item by its integer index).

Answer (score 3):

The reason to return `IEnumerable<T>` type is so that they caller cannot modify the list (without casting it back to a list).  If you notice all(most?) the extension methods take an `IEnumerable<T>` argument, so that you know that the extension method doesn't modify your list.

Secondly, `List<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

**Edit:**
As Thomas explained in a comment that the `IEnumerable<T>` could be cast back to a `List<T>` and modified by the caller.  If your main goal is to make it Read-Only, you can return the list as `myVar.AsReadOnly()`.  But then the type is `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: Not sure if preventing of modification is the main reason

Comment: It won't prevent the caller from modifying the list: the calling code can still cast the result to List<T>. However, doing so means making undocumented assumptions about the implementation, so it might break if the implementation changes.

Comment: And returning a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` preserves the array semantics of the returned value. That is, that an item can be retrieved by its integer index. And that a count of the items in the collection is available without the need to iterate the collection.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with it.

Actually returning concrete class is the only way to satisfy "returns interface" requirement.

There could be drawbacks if you let the knowledge of particular classes to sneak in to calling code (`List<T> r = (List<T>)MyMethod("ff")`). But if you treat result as interface (as you supposed to) it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't optimal, since it allows the caller to cast to `List<T>`, which relies on an implementation detail. I'd add some kind of masking, such as `Select(x=>x)`.

A dynamically typed caller might not even notice that you cast your list to `IEnumerable<T>`. For him it's simply `List<T>`.

Returning an internal permanent `List<T>` as `IEnumerable<T>` would be very wrong, since it allows the caller to mutate internal state of your class. But since you return a new instance of `List<T>` on every call, that's not used anywhere else, this argument doesn't apply in your example.

Comment: If you want to go that way, you might as well use an iterator ;)

Comment: Wrapping the list in something adds useless runtime baggage.  But maybe one could return a `List<T>` 99 times out of 100, and only return a wrapper occasionally?  That would break code which casts to `List`, but not hurt performance too badly.

Comment: @supercat Since for 99% of code this small overhead doesn't matter, I'd only worry about it if my profiling indicated that it's significant.