# How can I create class which is just List<string> with some custom methods?

Tags: c#, oop

It seems like a trivial task but I can't find how to do it (and don't know what to call it).

Example. I need class `state` that is in fact just list of strings. It must work so:

```
state s = new state();
s.Add("John Madden");
//s[0] == "John Madden"
```

And I need to add to this class some methods.

Comment: You could have `State` implement `IList<string>`.

Comment: You can create your own custom collection and enrich it with your custom methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Does `state` itself have to represent a list? or can it encapsulate one?

Comment: If your class really is just a `List<string>`, then maybe what you really want to do is go ahead and use a `List<string>` instead of defining your own class. The "custom methods" can simply be extension methods. Unfortunately, your question is fairly vague about what these "custom methods" really are, and why it is you feel you want a dedicated class for the `State` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just inherit from it:

```
public class State : List<string>
{}
```

That way, you have the full interface that [`List<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) offers, with your own type name. And then you can go, and add your own methods.

If you want a bit more control over it, e.g. to hide some methods or to change how they work, you could also create a wrapper class that implements [`IList<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) and just delegates most of its method to a private `List<string>` instance. E.g. like this:

```
public class State : IList<string>
{
    private List<string> internalList = new List<string>();

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return internalList[index]; }
        set { internalList[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Add (string item)
    {
        internalList.Add(item);
    }

    // etc. for the other IList<T> members
}
```

Comment: With this, you can even have the list populate itself with `this.Add("")` through the constructor.

Comment: It is a bad idea to inherit from `List<T>`. [Why not inherit from List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, i totally don't get what is bad in this?

Comment: @InfernumDeus Read the answers in the given link. You'll realize it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, i have pretty small project and state is actually list of some another objects, so i don't see a problem. To inherit from List looks nice as it extremely short solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirements, but maybe it would be a suitable approach to stick with List and use extension methods for your additional functionality.

```
public static class ListExtensions 
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithMyStrings (this List<string> list)
    {
        // Implement your additional functionality here
    }
}

// Usage:
using ListExtensions;

var myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("blah");
myList.DoSomethingWithMystrings ();
```

Comment: I'm actually have pretty messy classes structure and inherited class will make code more clear. But thank you for tip! I can use it in later projects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting a list, i would choose to encapsulate one (a great reason for *why* can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694054/1870803)).

If you need to have `State` hold custom, state related methods, they have nothing to do with a `List<string>` derived class.

```
public class State
{
    public List<string> FooBar { get; set; }

    public void Foo() { }
    public void Bar() { }
}
```

Comment: I agree that encapsulation is often a better approach but I don't necessarily agree with the sentiment of Eric's answer - in truth, trying to draw direct parallels between classes and their "real life" counterparts and derive technical solutions from those parallels is usually more harmful than useful - this kind of thing should generally be considered on its technical merits rather than its semantics. I'm sure purist DDD proponents would disagree with me but there you go.

Comment: @AntP That's alright, we don't have to agree. I simply think having custom methods on an inheretor of `List<T>` which aren't directly related to a `List<T>` would feel weird.

Comment: I don't disagree with that - that is simply good encapsulation. I just think that the basis of the other answer you linked to is too focused on deriving technical decisions on domain semantics rather than actual technical merit.

Comment: @InfernumDeus the public contract of your object that inherits from `List<string>` will look much worse (what does using LINQ on my state object accomplish?) and expose way more than you need to. An object that encapsulates the list will have a contract with methods and properties that explain exactly how you are supposed to interact with the object (instead of, say, being able to call `Aggregate()` over your state object).

Answer (score 0):

Try to inherit from `Collection<String>`, this is a better way then using List:  [Collection versus List what should you use on your interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271710/collectiont-versus-listt-what-should-you-use-on-your-interfaces)

```
public class State : Collection<string>
```

> List is not designed to be easily extensible by subclassing it; it
>   is designed to be fast for internal implementations. You'll notice the
>   methods on it are not virtual and so cannot be overridden, and there
>   are no hooks into its Add/Insert/Remove operations.

Comment: This sounds more like a reply to @poke 's answer. Not an answer itself.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It is clear an answer itself: inherit from Collection<String> instead from List<string>!

Comment: Question is not can I inherit from `List<string>`; if it were, then your answer *inherit from Collection<String> **instead** from List<string>* is fine. Also, you have edited the answer after my comment.