# C# Entity Framework .ToList() but CA1002: Use Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, list, collections

I am using Entity Framework to select entries from a database

```
List<Entry> entries = dbContext.entries.ToList();
```

Codeanalysis tells me Warning [CA1002](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182142.aspx): I found out that I should use `Collection` instead of `List`. But there is no `.ToCollection()` Method. Is this warning useless when using EF or what is the best practice there?

Update:
When doing

```
Collection<Entry> entries = dbContext.entries.ToList();
```

It says something like

> type List`<Entry>` can not be cast to Collection`<Entry>`

Comment: Collection<Entry> entries = dbContext.entries.ToList(); https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182142.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codeanalysis point in question is not complaining about your use of `ToList()` in the method, but rather that you're returning a `List<T>` from your method

If you change your signature (for example) then it will be happy:

```
public ICollection<Entry> GetEntries()
{
    return dbSet.Entries.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Okay returning ICollection fixed this. Now I can't use the find()-Method instead I have to use a Linq-Query I think.

Comment: Yes. It depends on how you want to use this elsewhere. Linq will work on collections, whereas Find will only work on List objects. Sometimes it makes sense to ignore code analysis recommendations depending on your particular use case

Comment: @L3n95 - it might be worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271710/collectiont-versus-listt-what-should-you-use-on-your-interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Not useless. What its saying is that rather than using generic list you could use one of the generic collections to store your results. 
I see that you are using EF, so most probably your `dbContext.Entries` is am `IQueryable` and when you use `ToList()` on it, it materializes the queryable and gives you the results.

So, to suppress the error you could use something like:

```
ICollection<Entry> collection = new List<Entry>();
```

or cast the results to a collection instead in a similar way

Comment: Okay returning ICollection fixed this. Now I can't use the find()-Method instead I have to use a Linq-Query I think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe write an extension method?
Haven't tested this code but something like this:

```
public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>
        (this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            }
            return new Collection<T>(source);
        }
```